# Can an elementary particle truly be destroyed?

Tags: particle-physics, conservation-laws, standard-model, elementary-particles

Much like the title above, can they be created (from absolute nothing) or destroyed (into absolute nothing), with nothing in this case being nonexistence. Taking into account the idea of quantum fields, or even just what we seem to understand in regards to annihilation and the various other processes, everything seems to suggest that at most an elementary particle can only be converted to a different form.

Of course, I am no physicist and just have an uneducated interest in this stuff, and have just had a hard time understanding what we have, given how confusing it is for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In any process involving the creation and annihilation of particles there will be conserved quantities that must be the same before and after the process, and the most obvious of these is energy. For example in the reaction between an electron and positron the electron and positron are destroyed, but since energy has to be conserved their energy has to be converted into something else, and that something else is (usually) two photons.

So it is impossible for a particle to just disappear into nothingness as this would violate conservation of energy.